# Probably a copyrighted question...about LaTeX Companion layout

Tags: geometry, pagestyle

Can I get the layout & font of LaTeX Companion book? I saw chapter 3 on LaTeX website and I like the layout. Also I have noticed that the page size is 7.33 x 9.21 in (in pdf).
I don't have the printed book, but is it the layout smaller than an A4 paper?

Comment: I think that the "companion" layout is one of the examples in the package "memoir"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The A4 page size is 297 by 210 mm (approximately 11 by 8 3/4 inches) so the Companion page is smaller than A4, as one might expect. `memoir` provides facilities for setting the page size and text size/placement. The `memoir` class provides a `companion` chapter style if you wish to use this.